# number guessing game with hints after certain number of tries. python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thank you for your patience everyone.

Thank you Ben10 for your answer. (posted below with my corrected print statements) My print statements were wrong. I needed to take the parenthesis out and separate the variable with commas on either side.
`print("It only took you ", counter, " attempts!")`

The number guessing game asks for hints after a certain number of responses as well as the option to type in cheat to have number revealed. One to last hints to to let the person guessing see if the number is divisible by another number. I wanted to have this hint available until the end of the game to help narrow down options of the number.

Again thank you everyone for your time and feedback.

[guessing_game.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0V3t.png)

```
import random

counter = 1
random_ = random.randint(1, 101)
print("Random number: ", random_) #Remove when releasing final prduct
divisor = random.randint(2, 6)
cheat = random_
print("I have generated a random number for you to guess (between 1-100)" )

while counter < 10:
    if counter == 3:
        print("Nope. Do you have what it takes? If not, type in 'cheat' to have the random number revealed.  ")
        if random_ % divisor == 0:
            print("Not it quite yet. The random number can be divided by ", divisor, ". ")
        else:
            print("Not it quite yet, The random number is NOT divisible by ", divisor, ". ")



    guess = input("What is your guess? ")
    #If the counter is above 3 then they are allowed to type 'cheat'
    if counter <= 3 and guess.lower() == "cheat":
        print("The number is ", cheat, ".")

    #If the player gets it right
    elif int(guess) == random_:
        print("You guessed the right number! :)")
        print("It only took you ", counter, " attempts!")
        #Break out of the while loop
        break




    #If the user types cheat , then we don't want the lines below to run as it will give us an error, hence the elif
    elif int(guess) < random_:
        print("Your guess is smaller than the random number. ")
    elif int(guess) > random_:
        print("Your guess is bigger than the random number. ")
    #Spacer to seperate attempts
    print("")


    counter += 1

#Print be careful as below code will run if they win or lose
if int(guess) != random_:
    print("You failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

Comment: Can you add the code to the question as text? A screenshot is much harder to work with.

Comment: Further to the above, please read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your print statement after the “else:” isn’t indented

Comment: you import `random` then assign it as a variable. this means you no longer have access to the module. PEP suggests to add a trailing `_` to mangle the variable if it is already used. `random_ = random.int(1, 101)`

Comment: I am finding it difficult to work out the intent behind the code, there are several suspected errors: `counter` and `attempts` appear to used as the same thing yet attempts is never initialized. the correct way to get a random int is `random.randint()`

Comment: guess 2 falls straight through to you guessed correctly.

Comment: Whenever you get a SyntaxError on a line that looks ok, look at the line before it. In this case, you forgot closing parentheses (or accidentally put them in quotes) in a couple of spots. Note that this is certainly not the only issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the code, to allow it to be more versitile. Noticed quite a few errors, like how you forgot to put a closing bracket at the end of a print statement. Also in the print statements you were doing String concatenation (where you combine strings together) incorrectly.

```
import random

counter = 1
random_ = random.randint(1, 101)
print("Random number: " + str(random_)) #Remove when releasing final prduct
divisor = random.randint(2, 6)
cheat = random_
print("I have generated a random number for you to guess (between 1-100)" )

while counter < 5:
    if counter == 3:
        print("Nope. Do you have what it takes? If not, type in 'cheat' to have the random number revealed.  ")
        if random_ % divisor == 0:
            print("Not it quite yet. The random number can be divided by " + str(divisor) + ". ")
        else:
            print("Not it quite yet, The random number is NOT divisible by " + str(divisor) + ". ")



    guess = input("What is your guess? ")
    #If the counter is above 3 then they are allowed to type 'cheat'
    if counter <= 3 and guess.lower() == "cheat":
        print("The number is " + str(cheat) +".")

    #If the player gets it right
    elif int(guess) == random_:
        print("You guessed the right number! :)")
        print("It only took you " + str(counter) + " attempts!")
        #Break out of the while loop
        break




    #If the user types cheat , then we don't want the lines below to run as it will give us an error, hence the elif
    elif int(guess) < random_:
        print("Your guess is smaller than the random number. ")
    elif int(guess) > random_:
        print("Your guess is bigger than the random number. ")
    #Spacer to seperate attempts
    print("")


    counter += 1

#Print be careful as below code will run if they win or lose
if int(guess) != random_:
    print("You failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```